# Transform sql code to bigquery sql (eomonth)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to split my monthly Values in daily values. The monthly value also split by the number of days of the month. I found a SQL query but I cant apply the query in Bigquery.
How can I apply this query in BigQuery? Are there any options instead of eomonth?

```
with cte as

 (
select 
    targetdate, 
    eomonth(targetdate) enddate, 
    1.0 * units / day(eomonth(targetdate)) units
from targettable
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, targetdate), enddate, units 
from cte
where targetdate < enddate ) 

select targetdate, units from cte
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: The example you provided provides the days from `targetdate` up to but not including the last day of the month (on MSSQL?).  The description leads me to believe that you want all of the days of the month.  If target table has 1 row with `targetdate='2021-01-10'` how many rows do you want back?

Answer (score 0):

[`last_day`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#last_day) is the Bigquery function equivalent of `eomonth`.

Bigquery's [`generate_date_array`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) is a better solution than the recursive CTE in your example. Which is lucky as Bigquery does not support recursive CTEs.

Here's the answer:

```
with targettable as (
    SELECT date('2022-01-10') as targetdate, 31 as units
)
select days,
  last_day(targettable.targetdate) enddate,
  units / extract(day from days) as units
from targettable
cross join unnest(generate_date_array(targettable.targetdate, last_day(targettable.targetdate))) as days
```

The CTE is just for example data.  `generate_date_array` gives an `array` which we `unnest` into rows.  That happens in the `from` clause with a `cross join` as there is no join criteria, other than parameters to the function.

The "units" calculation is weird in the initial example.  `extract(day from days)` gives the day of the month as an `int64`, which is what the original does.